# cakePHP - modified field not updating

Tags: cakephp

Any ideas on how to debug a modified field that is not being updated? The created field works fine.

I'm not sure what code you would need to look at so let me know!

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like Anh Pham said, the `modified` and `created` field need to be `DATETIME` and they also need to default to `NULL`, as [explained in the CakePHP book about the subject](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1015/created-and-modified).

Comment: Yeap, they are both DATETIME, and default to NULL. Created does work, however when calling $this->Model->save() in the edit function it does not update the modified field.

Comment: you probably provide those fields again in the form. those are not allowed to be present in the form or on save to be updated correctly!

Answer (score 6):

Most likely you are overwriting the field, unset the field from the object before saving it like this:

```
unset($user['User']['modified']);
```

Now you can save it:

```
$this->User->save($user);
```

Comment: This is not an issue when you save data that was previously found from DB but it's indeed a problem when you populate from other sources (session, request...).

Answer (score 5):

You should try checking if you didn't use

```
 $this->ModelName->read(NULL, $id);
```

before saving your data, if you think you didn't - double check it

Answer (score 1):

That field should be named 'modified' with 'datetime' type. Cake should update the field automatically for you. If you want to check, just query it, or look into the database.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem today and found out the `modified` field is **only updated if any changes have been made**, otherwise the field will not be touched.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might also arise if you use manual update queries. The field is updated only when you use Cake's own functions.

Comment: I am using the Model->save() function.

Answer (score 0):

In AppModel.php, just write the following code.

```
public function beforeSave($options = array())  {
    parent::beforeSave();
    if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['modified'])) {
        unset($this->data[$this->alias]['modified']);
    }
    if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['created'])) {
        unset($this->data[$this->alias]['created']);
    }

}
```

This will work for all models. But we can do that for individual MODELS too.

Since we have used `parent::beforeSave();` as our first line therefore **this can be overwritten in each individual MODEL**.
Thanks to inheritance.

Comment: This will leave the modified and created fields as null in the database, at least in my version of Cake.

Comment: I have tried this in cake 2.X. Which cake version you are using ?

Comment: I am using version 2.3.1.

Comment: It has been left as null in the DB since you did not set the type of column as TIMESTAMP. If you will use this datatype for the columns then these will automatically be updated.